# Laravel landing page routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have two different routes in my web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'Web\DashboardController@index');

Route::get('/my-page/{alias}', 'Web\MyPageController@index');
```

I want to make the second page as my landing page without changing URLs. Like when visitor come to website it land to `http://www.url.com/my-page/{alias}`

Comment: So what happens to non-visitors? Or do you want a simple redirect to /my-page?

Comment: Simple redirect, like just want to indicate this one is my landing page.

Answer (score 3):

There is multiple ways to achieve this, of which two common ones are:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $alias = ...; // find an alias
    return redirect()->route('mypage', ['alias' => $alias]);
});

Route::get('/my-page/{alias}', 'Web\MyPageController@index')->name('mypage');
```

or

```
Route::redirect('/', '/my-page/fixed-alias', 301);

Route::get('/my-page/{alias}', 'Web\MyPageController@index');
```